# UITableView exists in .h file, but .m file says tableView does not exist?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, view, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.5

So fairly basic question (not sure why this is happening to me)... UITableView clearly exists on my .h file, but for some reason when I call tableView in my .m file, it says, "Property tableView not found on object of type ViewController." And when I change 'UIViewController' in the @interface line to 'UITableViewController', the app throws me an error? Help :)

**.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <PickerViewControllerDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UITableView *strainTableView;

NSArray *Strains;
NSArray *searchResults;

NSMutableData *data;
NSMutableArray *dataArray;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *searchResults;


@end
```

**.m**

```
- (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
        [self tableView: self.tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
    }
}
```

Comment: But you do not have `tableView` property, only the `strainTableView` variable. Am I missing something?

Comment: Okay, so the outlet strainTableView is connected to the actual UITableView object (on my storyboard). When I create TableView as a property, and then link it to the UITableView also, I get an error. Note that the TableView object is sitting inside of a regular ViewController.

Comment: I do not know if you can have two `IBOutlet`s connected to the same object in the NIB. You should be able to make `strainTableView` a property, though. Renaming it to just `tableView` should work as well.

Comment: Tried both. If I make StrainTableView a property, EG: @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *StrainTableView, it causes an error...

Comment: Ahhh fixed it. Removed the outlet from my property. Changed to: @property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;